# SKSpriteNode setting color in init(NSCoder)

Tags: swift, sprite-kit, skspritenode, nscoder

I use XCode 7.2.1 to create a SKSpriteNode in the SceneEditor (with custom class = PlayerNode)

I found that Node load from a SKS file are initialized with the method init(coder: NSCoder) so here how i implement PlayerNode class in swift

```
class PlayerNode : SKSpriteNode {
    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)
        self.initializePhysics()
    }

    func initializePhysics() {
        /* blabla */
        self.color = SKColor.greenColor()
        self.colorBlendFactor = 1.0
        self.blendMode = .Replace
    }
}
```

When i run the project, the node color do not change not even a little.
But when i change the color in the method didMoveToView of GameScene object, like:

```
class GameScene: SKScene {

    var player = SKSpriteNode()

    override func didMoveToView(view: SKView) {
        super.didMoveToView(view)
        self.player = (self.childNodeWithName("player") as? SKSpriteNode)!

        self.player.color = SKColor.greenColor()
        self.player.colorBlendFactor = 1.0
        self.player.blendMode = .Replace
    }
}
```

Now the color change.
Is there a way to set color in the PlayerNode class ?

Answer (score 0):

You created a SKSpriteNode:

```
var player = SKSpriteNode()
```

But you want:

```
var player = PlayerNode()
```

Comment: It's not important, as i override player in didMoveToView() method

Comment: @user3682658 what do you mean with "not important"? What i wrote is what causes your Problem. 100%.

Comment: @user3682658 your cast to your SkSpriteNode in your didMoveToView() is wrong too. Your initializePhysics() never gets called

Comment: PlayerNode is created when the scene load the GameScene.sks.  Here a  [screenshot](http://tinypic.com/r/29zd1lh/9) with debug messages so you can check. And here the [github project](https://github.com/pgoergler/TestSKSpriteNode)

Comment: @Paul Yes but you override your player after your creation. The way you implemented your Player is wrong. Your project works when i change what i suggested

Comment: I have change to var player: PlayerNode? but it does not work, the color of the ship did not change. I have also remove everything in GameScene.swift and the color of ship did not change neither (the intializer of PlayerNode class is still correctly called)